# Magento-when to use Mage::getResourceModel and Mage::getModel

Tags: magento

I just started to use Magento, and in particular on how models and the ORM work.

I have used these three methods

```
Mage::getResourceModel()
Mage::getModel()
Mage::getSingleton()
```

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between each of them?

I have found that `getSingleton()` shares memory while `getModel()` uses fresh memory for new object for the same table being loaded.

I have used all the methods above but could not differentiate between them and when is appropriate to use which one.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Perfect differece with example for getsingleton and getmodel.**

**Mage::getSingleton()**

Mage::getSingleton() will first check if the same class instance exists or not in the memory. If the instance exists then it will return the same object from the memory. So Mage::getSingleton() is faster than Mage::getModel().

Example

```
$product1 = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
$product2 = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
```

$product1 and $product2 both will share same memory of OS and return only one instance each time.

**Mage::getModel()**

Mage::getModel() will create a new instance of an object each time even such object exists in configuration.

Example

```
$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

$product1 and $product2 both have different instant of same object and also occupy different memory

**Mage::getResourceModel()**

As far as I know, all collections in Magento are resource models. They are instantiated by

```
Mage::getResourceModel()
```

or

```
Mage::getModel()->getCollection()
```

It doesn't really matter which function you use; the latter one simply calls the first one. The Magento team simply chose to make collections part of the resource, probably because collections need to query the database a lot. Usually, you will not have to call `Mage::getResourceModel()` for anything else than collections.

good post by balajimca

Comment: god bless your soul for this explanation.

Comment: How to call selected category of products in observer using category id? @Sam

Answer (score 11):

Also if you know what attributes you need then using Mage::getResourceModel with filters is ~5x more efficient in both speed and memory than loading via say Mage::getModel('catalog/product').

e.g.
getResourceModel method of retrieving a product from the db

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array($productId))
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
    ->setPageSize(1);
$product = $collection->getFirstItem();
```

load a model (this will load all eav attributes)

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

[more info here][1]
http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1

Comment: This helped, but I had to use `->addFieldToSelect('name_of_field')` on a non-product based concrete class extending `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`

Comment: @LeoFisher yes, you need to use addFieldToSelect([]) for non EAV collections